# If every element of $G/H$ has a square root and every element of $H$ has a square root, then every element of $G$ has a square root.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, quotient-group

I have tried to prove this statement but cannot. Does it require the group $G$ to be abelian? This assumption is not stated in the text I am reading, but all I can get is that if we consider that $gH = b^2H$ for some $b$, then $gb^{-2} \in H$ so $gb^{-2} = f^2$ for some $f$, but it requires the group to be abelian to say $g = (bf)^2$.

Comment: If $G$ is finite then this is easy because every element has a square root iff $G$ has odd order. In general I don't see it.

Comment: Here is my stab at it: Note that since $H$ is (presumably) a normal subgroup of $G$ (as we need the construction $G/H$ to make sense), we know that for all $g\in G$
$$
gH = Hg.
$$
Thus when we write $g = hb^2$, there has to be some $h' \in H$ such that 
$$
g=bh'b.
$$
Write $h'=f^2$ for $f\in H$. Since $f\in H$, there must be some $x\in H$ such that $bf=xb$. Thus we get
$$
g=bf^2b=xbfb = x^2b^2.
$$

The only assumption I believe I have made is that "Every element of H has a square root" means a square root in $H$.

Thanks for the awesome question :D !

Comment: This requires the group to be abelian; otherwise, $x^2b^2$ is not necessarily a square, @wbitting95.

Comment: Oh phooey. You're right.

Comment: How is $xbfb=x^2b^2$, @wbitting95?

Comment: xbfb = x (bf) b = x (xb) b, as we assumed that bf=xb via the normality of $H$. Your comment that x^2b^2 need not be a square still holds though and is definitely a major oversight on my part haha.

Comment: I see. Thank you, @wbitting95 :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is false if one leaves the realm of abelian groups or finite groups. Theorem 1.4 of Wehrfritz's *The divisible radical of a group* produces a non-divisible metabelian $2$-group that is the product of two of its divisible normal subgroups. It is a subgroup of the wreath product of two Pruefer groups $2^\infty$.

Comment: Thanks! I can't say I understand this all, but it's good to know there is a counterexample.